# How do you get all ancestors of a node using SQL Server 2008 hierarchyid?

Tags: sql-server, hierarchyid

Given a table with a `hierarchyid` type column, how do you write a query to return all rows that are ancestors of a specific node?

There is an `IsDescendantOf()` function, which is perfect for getting the children, but there's no corresponding `IsAncestorOf()` function to return ancestors (and the absence of a `GetAncestors()` function seems like quite an oversight.)

Comment: Isn't `child.IsDescendantOf(parent)` the same as `parent.IsAncestorOf(child)`?

Comment: @Gabe Yes, if `IsAncestorOf(node)` had existed, they would be equivalent. No need for recursive queries for this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The most commonly used approach would be a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE)

```
WITH Ancestors(Id, [Name], AncestorId) AS
(
      SELECT
            Id, [Name], Id.GetAncestor(1)
      FROM
            dbo.HierarchyTable
      WHERE
            Name = 'Joe Blow'  -- or whatever you need to select that node

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
            ht.Id, ht.[Name], ht.Id.GetAncestor(1)
      FROM
            dbo.HierarchyTable ht
      INNER JOIN 
            Ancestors a ON ht.Id = a.AncestorId
)
SELECT *, Id.ToString() FROM Ancestors
```

(adapted from a [Simon Ince blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160223140338/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/simonince/archive/2008/10/17/hierarchies-with-hierarchyid-in-sql-2008.aspx))

Simon Ince also proposes a second approach where he just basically reverses the condition - instead of detecting those person entries that are an ancestor of the target person, he turns the check around:

```
DECLARE @person hierarchyid

SELECT @person = Id
FROM dbo.HierachyTable
WHERE [Name] = 'Joe Blow';

SELECT
    Id, Id.ToString() AS [Path], 
    Id.GetLevel() AS [Level],
    Id.GetAncestor(1),
    Name
FROM 
    dbo.HierarchyTable
WHERE 
    @person.IsDescendantOf(Id) = 1
```

This will select all the rows from your table, where the target person you're interested in is a descendant of - any level down the hierarchy. So this will find that target person's immediate and non-immediate ancestors all the way up to the root.

Comment: In that blogpost, isn't this CTE solution then followed by a simpler one ("This works fine, but is it the optimum way of achieving it? Nope. Let’s try again!") ?

Comment: @AakashM: yes, there is a second option, indeed - not one that I would probably use, but it will work, too, from the looks of it.

Comment: I know this is very old, but I write this for future readers: The method from "Simon Ince blog post" is nearly 100 times slower than the "CTE" method when the execution plan doesn't exist.

Comment: Yup @Achilles, it is probably because the query becomes non-sargable when you apply IsDescendantOf function to ID of every row. I am always getting an index scan with the query. The recursive CTE seems to be a much better option.

Answer (score 17):

Here's an answer rolled into a single select:

```
SELECT t1.Id.ToString() as Path, t1.Name
    FROM (SELECT * FROM HierarchyTable
        WHERE Name = 'Joe Blow') t2,
    HierarchyTable t1
    WHERE t2.Id.IsDescendantOf(t1.Id) = 1
```

Comment: The first predicate of the where clause is redundant since a parent is always a descendant of itself.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677203(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @hid hierarchyid=0x5D10 -- Child hierarchy id

SELECT
*
FROM 
  dbo.TableName
WHERE 
  @hid.IsDescendantOf(ParentHierarchyId) = 1
```

Comment: Even if you have an index on the hierarchyID, it will have to evaluate IsDesendentOf for every row, no? I think I have a better way (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a user-defined table-valued function that expands a hierarchyid value into its constituent ancestors. The output can then be joined back on the hierarchyid column to get those ancestors specifically.

```
alter function dbo.GetAllAncestors(@h hierarchyid, @ReturnSelf bit)
returns table
as return
 select @h.GetAncestor(n.Number) as h
 from dbo.Numbers as n
 where n.Number <= @h.GetLevel()
  or (@ReturnSelf = 1 and n.Number = 0)

 union all

 select @h
 where @ReturnSelf = 1
go
```

To go about using it:

```
select child.ID, parent.ID
from dbo.yourTable as child
cross apply dbo.GetAllAncestors(child.hid, 1) as a
join dbo.yourTable as parent
   on parent.hid = a.h
```

Comment: please help me to solve this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016261/how-do-you-get-recursivelevel-using-sql-server-2012-hierarchyid

Comment: I recently had to solve this problem and I believe this is the best solution offered here.  The other solutions that pass a column reference into IsDescendantOf() have to resolve that predicate in the Query Executor and not the Storage Engine.  If you have any amount of data, performance will be terrible.

Comment: I've since written aCLR function that does the same thing.

Comment: I like how you think.  I'm going to steal that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Perfecting Ben Thui's answer which I find to be the best one so far...

The approach below allows to retrieve not only one but potentially several leaf rows and their ascendants in one single query.

```
Create Or Alter Function dbo.GetAllAncestors
(
    @Path       HierarchyId,
    @WithSelf   Bit = 1,
    @MinLevel   Int = 0,
    @MaxLevel   Int = Null
)
Returns Table
As
Return

With Ancestor As
(
    Select  @Path As Path
    Union All

    Select  Path.GetAncestor(1)
    From    Ancestor
    Where   Path.GetLevel() > 0
)

Select  Path, Path.GetLevel() As Level
From    Ancestor
Where   (@WithSelf = 1 Or Path <> @Path)
And     Path.GetLevel() >= Case When @MinLevel < 0 Or @MinLevel Is Null Then 0 Else @MinLevel End
And     (@MaxLevel Is Null Or Path.GetLevel() <= @MaxLevel)
```

To use:

```
-- This assumes the table has a Path HierarchyId colum, and the values are unique and indexed.

-- If you know the path
Select *
From MyTable
Where Path In
(
    Select Path From dbo.GetAllAncestors(@ThePath, Default, Default, Default)
)

-- If you don't know the path
Select *
From MyTable t1
Where Path In 
(
    Select Path
    From   MyTable t2
           Cross Apply dbo.GetAllAncestors(t2.Path, Default, Default, Default)
    Where  /* Find the leaf record(s) here.
              Note that if multiple rows match, they will all be returned as well as their parents in a single roundtrip. */
)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @hid_Specific HIERARCHYID 
SET @hid_Specific = '/1/1/3/1/';

SELECT hrchy_id,* FROM tblHierarchyData 
WHERE PATINDEX(hrchy_id.ToString() + '%', @hid_Specific.ToString()) = 1
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation to your solution?