# SQL: Finding the Lowest Common Ancestor of hierarchyids

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent, hierarchyid, ancestor

I have a dataset containing (among others) the values hierarchyids and the Parent-hierarchyids.
For another query I need the lowest common ancestor of the hierarchyids and since I am fairly new to sql and espacially hierarchyids.

```
ID          HID         ParentHID
1           0x5CB280    0x5CA0
2           0x5CABBB08  0x5CABBA
3           0x5CB270    0x5CA0
```

Comment: The lowest common ancestor to what? Please provide an example of your requirements and of your data set: do you have two fields, one that is an id and one that is the parent id of the record?

Comment: did some edit, hope its somewhat easier to understand now

Comment: Is Microsoft SQL? If yes I have a link to doc showing the answer, but I don't wanna post it if I'm not sure about the SQL Server you're using! :)

Comment: woops yea, its Microsoft SQL. I would be very grateful if you could provide the link

Comment: Well, I'm not posting it as an answer because it needs to be worked out but this is the tech link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx This describes the main hierarchyid API and how to find LCA with a DLL in C#. I'm trying to find something ready and simple, if I can I'll post an answer, so stay tuned! :D

Comment: And this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119860/how-do-you-get-all-ancestors-of-a-node-using-sql-server-2008-hierarchyid has an answer with a query to get all the ancestors of a record: I think it could be figured out how to cross result for two records and get common ancestors...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your hierarchy is not severely balance-skewed (e.g. a list) getting ancestor chain is cheap. Next, all you have to do is take two ancestor chains, make set intersection, and then find a longest hierarchy id.